# R gVisScatterChart viewWindowMode explicit

Tags: r, google-visualization

I try to create a Scatter-Chart with gVis on R. I want to define my vAxis manually, but can not figure out what I am doing wrong. It  works as if the WindowMode still would be 'pretty'

```
 Scatter <- gvisScatterChart(data, 
                                options=list(legend="none",
                                             lineWidth=1, pointSize=2, 
                                             hAxis.gridlines.count = 3,
                                             vAxis.viewWindowMode='explicit',
                                             vAxis.viewWindow.max=24,
                                             vAxis.viewWindow.min=0,
                                             width=150, height=600))
```

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Scatter <- gvisScatterChart(dat, 
                 options=list(legend="none",
                              lineWidth=1, pointSize=2, 
                              hAxis.gridlines.count = 3,
                              pointSize=0, 
                              lineWidth=2,
                              vAxis = list( list(viewWindowMode = "explicit",
                                            viewWindow = list(max = 24, min = 0))),
                              width=150, height=600))
```